# Is there a way to add and run a cluster configuration without rebooting the broker?

Tags: activemq-artemis

Or there is only one way - add the configuration to the `broker.xml` and restart the broker, only then the cluster will work. I found in `embeddedActiveMQ.getActiveMQServer()` the `.getClusterManager()` method, can I do it somehow with the `ClusterManager`?

**Update**

This way (clusterManager - stop - deploy - start) works, but sometimes the following exceptions occur

```java
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Server locator is closed (maybe it was garbage collected)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ServerLocatorImpl.assertOpen(ServerLocatorImpl.java:1848)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ServerLocatorImpl.createSessionFactory(ServerLocatorImpl.java:648)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ServerLocatorImpl.connect(ServerLocatorImpl.java:549)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ServerLocatorImpl.connect(ServerLocatorImpl.java:528)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.cluster.ClusterController$ConnectRunnable.run(ClusterController.java:433)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.OrderedExecutor.doTask(OrderedExecutor.java:42)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.OrderedExecutor.doTask(OrderedExecutor.java:31)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.ProcessorBase.executePendingTasks(ProcessorBase.java:65)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.ActiveMQThreadFactory$1.run(ActiveMQThreadFactory.java:118)
```

Comment: What's the use-case for adding or removing a broker from a cluster dynamically at runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is theoretically possible. Once the broker is started you'd need to stop the `ClusterManager` using the `stop()` method. Then you could update the broker's `Configuration` and then invoke `deploy()` and `start()` on the `ClusterManager`.

I've not done this before so it's possible you'll encounter problems. It may, in fact, be simpler & safer to just stop & start the broker itself.

Comment: this way works, but sometimes the following exceptions occur (above, in the description). Can this exception do any harm? Maybe somehow you can get rid of it? use-case - I would like to add or remove cluster nodes at runtime (static list of connectors) or change connection properties so that the broker is always available.

Comment: Typically in a use-case where cluster nodes can come and go you'd use dynamic discovery (e.g. via UDP multicast or through the JGroups integration which supports all kinds of discovery mechanisms) rather than static configuration. As for the exception, I would need a way to reproduce it to investigate further.